# DocuSign API - How to implement "Need to View"

Tags: docusignapi

I am integrating our Saas Solution with DocuSign using DocuSign API.

I would like to know the appropriate "Recipient type" to implement a Review only participant.The intent of the participant is that he will be a passive participant who has to view the document.

I see the documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipient%20Parameter.htm) -  but none of the recipient types seem to be meant for this use case.

Note:The current implementation does not orchestrate the flow step by step.All the participants are specified once at the beginning of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the recipient type "CertifiedDelivery". As the documentation describes 
[here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Certified%20Deliveries%20Recipient.htm) :

*Use this action if the recipient must receive the completed documents for the envelope to be completed, but **the recipient does not need to sign, initial, date or add information to any of the documents.***